# I'm having an issue detecting multiple different collisions in SpriteKit (Obj-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm building a game using Objective-C and SpriteKit. In this game, there are asteroids that come down at the player, who has to avoid them. Asteroids are spawned every 0.5 seconds. There is another type of asteroid, "gold asteroids" which use a different variable in-game, and can be shot at to get coins.

Another part of the game involves buying new "ships" to navigate through the asteroids. One ship has the special ability of being able to shoot at regular asteroids to destroy them as well as the golden ones. This is where the problem begins.

This is the code that detects the collisions between regular asteroids and bullets. A lot of the code comes from Sangony's answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068043/issue-with-multiple-different-collions-in-spritekit-ios-app-written-in-objectiv) StackOverflow post.

```
NSString *playerImage = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                         stringForKey:@"playerImage"];

if ([playerImage  isEqual: @"crazyben.png"]) //make sure the ship is the one with the special ability to destroy regular asteroids, not where the issue is
{
    NSLog(@"Crazy Ben Enabled");
    uint32_t collision3 = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

    if (collision3 == (bulletCategory | asteroidCategory))
    {
        NSLog(@"collision3");
        for (SKSpriteNode * object in self.asteroidArray);
        {
            NSLog(@"for statement");
            if ([contact.bodyA.node.name
                  isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asteroid-%i", self.asteroidCounter]] ||[contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asteroid-%i", self.asteroidCounter]]) //broken here, it only allows you to detect a collision between the bullet and the asteroid that currently matches up to the "self.asteroidCounter" int
            {
                NSLog(@"crazyhit");
                [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"gunshot.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];
                [self.bullet removeFromParent];
                [self.asteroid removeFromParent];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The part that is broken is the part when it's time to detect the collisions. Using this code, you are only able to destroy the asteroid that corresponds to the self.asteroidCounter integer, which is the most recently spawned asteroid. If I remove the line

```
NSLog(@"for statement");
            if ([contact.bodyA.node.name
                  isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asteroid-%i", self.asteroidCounter]] ||[contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asteroid-%i", self.asteroidCounter]])
```

to allow it to destroy the asteroid regardless of whether or not it has the same number as self.asteroidCounter, instead of destroying the specific asteroid that was hit, it appears to simply destroy a random asteroid that is on the screen instead.

What I want is for the asteroid that was actually hit to be removed from the parent.

Thanks in advance, and if there is any information missing or if you would like a clarification, I will gladly add or clarify it.

EDIT: I edited the code, and added variables for asteroidCounter B through J. asteroidCounterB = asteroidCounterA - 1, asteroidCounterC = asteroidCounterB - 1 and so on. With this, I get a behaviour identical to when I was treating them all alike, with the same name, rather than identifying them using the asteroidCounter variables. Now I believe that the issue is in the code that says

```
[self.asteroid removeFromParent];
```

When it does that, it does not remove a specific asteroid from the parent, it just removes one of them from the parent. If I remove all the asteroidCounter variables (apart from the original), is there a way that I could say something like this?

```
[self.asteroid-%i removeFromParent];
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, but it would be great if there was a way to get something like that.

Comment: Have you tried creating 2 arrays? One for regular asteroids and one for gold asteroids. This might make your code easier to process.

Comment: @sangony Well, the gold asteroid doesn't really need an array, it's actually a completely separate thing from the regular ones. As there is only one gold one on the screen at a time, I don't have the same issue as with the regular ones. With the regular ones, there are many on-screen at once, and rather than removing the one that was hit, it just removes one in a way that appears fairly random.

Comment: I think you are getting confused on why I suggested using a unique name for each node. You should be looping through the asteroid array and seeing which asteroid matches up with the name of the contacted asteroid.

Comment: @sangony do you think you could tell me exactly how to do that? I wanted a unique name for each one so that I would be able to determine which asteroid was hit, and destroy that specific one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a unique name for each node, an easy way is to just add a number at the end of the name.

```
self.objectID++;
myNode.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myNode-%lu",self.objectID];
```

self.object being a property `@property (nonatomic) long objectID;`

To check which of your 'myNode' objects was involved with a collision you can do this:

```
if (collision == (bulletCategory | asteroidCategory)) {

    for(SKSpriteNode *object in self.asteroidArray) {
        if(([object.name isEqualToString:contact.bodyB.node.name]) || ([object.name isEqualToString:contact.bodyA.node.name])) {
                // your code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be the same code I'm currently using, but with different variables and a long rather than an integer. Would using long instead of int make a difference here?

Comment: @JustMe - The code is similar and using a long instead of an int does not make a difference in this case. The line in your code: ** if ([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asteroid-%i", self.asteroidCounter]] ||[contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asteroid-%i", self.asteroidCounter]]) ** only checks if a collision has taken place with the most recent asteroid created.

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to test for each different case individually. Start by setting up different static category bit masks like you have already done

```
static const uint32_t normalAstroidCategory = 0x1 << 0;
static const uint32_t goldAstroidCategory = 0x1 << 1;
static const uint32_t normalBullets = 0x1 << 2;
static const uint32_t specialBullets = 0x1 << 3;
```

Then make sure you set up so that the right bullets have the right contactTestBitMasks as well as CategoryBitMasks.

```
//Code used for special bullets
specialBullet.categoryBitMask = specialBullet;
specialBullet.contactTestBitMask = normalAstroidCategory | goldAstroidCategory
//Code used for normal bullets
normalBullet.categoryBitMask = normalBullet;
normalBullet.contactTestBitMask = normalAstroidCategory
```

Make sure you also set the right bit mask for the astroids as well

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact*)contact{
    if (contact.bodyA == normalBullets || contact.bodyB == normalBullets 
        || contact.bodyA == specialBullets || contact.bodyB == specialBullets)
    {
        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == goldAstroidCategory || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == goldAstroidCategory){
            gold++;
        }
    }
}
```

You may have to put in additional logic if you are worried about the ship colliding with astroids as well. Also try saving a ship type in NSUserDefaults instead of an image name because its more reliable or use an enum maybe to see whether the ship is of a certain type